# How to access CDROM in a simple Linux initrd filesystem made by busybox?

Tags: linux-kernel, cd-rom

Here's my situation:

I made a simple bootable ISO file for x86-64 architecture using 6.3-rc1 Linux bzimage, a simple initrd filesystem made by busybox and grub.

I boot it up with virtualbox, and I tried to mount the /dev/sr0, it shows error `mount:mounting /dev/sr0 on /mnt/cdrom failed: Invalid argument`. Also, the kernel shows  error: `[ timestamp] /dev/sr0: can't open blockdev`
So my question is that how can I access the CDROM in this situation? I trid googled but found nothing useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so does /dev/sr0 exists?

Comment: Sure it does exist, I checked before I want to access it.

Comment: Is the sr_mod module loaded?

Comment: yes, it is a builtin module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I can't mount the `/dev/sr0` in initrd mode is that The configuration file for the kernel I compiled sets the iso9660 file system to "m", and I didn't load the iso file system module.

So after I load the `isofs.ko`, problem solved.